# Is there a borel set $A$ and a linear map $f$ such that $f(A)$ is not borel?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Is there a borel set $A\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and a linear map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ that $f(A)$ is not borel set?

I think there is but I can't find it.

Comment: Is $f$ continuous — a standard linear map, and not just some (possibly freakish) thing satisfying $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ taking $\Bbb R^n$ as a $\Bbb Q$ vector space. Probably yes - just checking.

Comment: @BrianO yes since it's a linear map of Rn to Rn

Comment: Just checking that it wasn't a trick question about a Hamel basis. Pointlessly, I now think.

Comment: @hctb In order to clarify following previous comments. Which field are you considering when you speak of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a vector space?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net just R

Comment: If $f$ is 1-1 then the image of any Borel $A$ is Borel, so you'll need $f$ with a nonzero kernel — a projection, with the right basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Projection is a linear map and there are Borel subsets of plane that project to non Borel subsets of line.

Comment: Can you show an explicit example? Thanks.

Comment: You need to give an example or a reference for this to be an answer.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34142/projection-of-borel-set-from-r2-to-r1  Apparently Lebesgue himself made a mistake thinking the projection of a Borel set was a Borel set.

Comment: A $\bf\Sigma^1_1$ (analytic) set that is not $\bf\Delta^1_1$ (Borel) —for example, a complete $\bf\Sigma^1_1$ set — will be a non-Borel projection of a Borel set: it's $\{x\mid \exists y\, B(x,y)\}$ for some Borel $B$. One can define it fairly explicitly, but it involves a respectable buildup of definitions — trees, (non)wellfounded trees, the branches through a tree as a set of reals, and so on. Standard results and constructions in descriptive set theory, but not just a few lines.